# rating for the business from the Google Places API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, google-api, asp.net-4.0

I am new to this but i need some examples or tutorial to start with.

have to create a web page that takes information about a business (name, address, web address, etc.) and then gets the average review rating for the business from the Google Places API. This project must be built on the Asp.Net MVC version 3, using .Net 4.0.

Any links or help is greatly appreciated.

I am going through these links..

http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2011/05/places-everybody-show-is-about-to-begin.html

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/

Answer (score 1):

Check out http://www.asp.net/mvc for some great tutorials. It looks like you are on the right track for Google Places API.

EDIT: In response to your comment, it looks Google has a JavaScript API for accessing Google Maps / Places. Please see [this](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#MVCObject) link for more information. What you would have to do is include the proper .js files into the web pages that need them.

Also [here](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/index.html) they have samples of using the places js API (scroll to the bottom).

Since the data is exposed via Json through an http request, you could also use [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx), and parse the data your self.

Comment: thanks for the start... but i cannot find any good tutorial on how to integrate a google API with MVC..